# Oracle WebLogic 12c Deployment Plan Archive?

Tags: oracle, deployment, weblogic

I am trying to find any documentation on using a Deployment Plan Archive for WLS 12c, but I am not finding any.

I did find this old thread: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2293718

> "Deployment Plan Archive" Option that we have in WebLogic Console at Deployment Service is new feature added from 11G and currently not under full fledged implementation, so that's the reason its not documented in any of the Oracle Documentation.

We are after using the Admin Console to deploy our application and to use our deployment plans (Plan.xml), but the Upload a deployment plan wants a jar not a xml file.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to select both the application war/ear file and below the plan, then upload both.